# Magento: How to show a date in PHP with an attribute date

Tags: php, magento, date, attributes

I've created a attribute-set called pdmset1 and pdmset2 where pdmset1 is a YES/NO attribute and pdmset2 a date.

I echo both by the following php-code

```
 echo "PDMSET1: " . Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('pdmset1')
 echo "PDMSET2: Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('pdmset2')
```

Output is the following:

```
>> PDMSET1: YES 
>> PDMSET2:
```

So it seems to me PDMSET2 is empty or so. Can somebody explain to me what I do wrong and even better what to do so I get the correct date for PDMSET2

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid.  Please post the code you actually have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your attribute is set up correctly, you should be able to do $product->getData('pdmset2'). 
The problem with your code is that getAttributeText() method is used for getting attributes that use sources (such as drop-down select box), as seen in Mage_Catalog_Model_Product:

```
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
    {
        return $this->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
                ->getSource()
                    ->getOptionText($this->getData($attributeCode));
    }
```

Your Yes/ No is a select so getAttributeText works, but for date you should just use getData, your code should look something like this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
echo $product->getAttributeText('pdmset1');
echo $product->getData('pdmset2');   // or $product->getPdmset2();
```

Also note that loading an object using id is memory consuming, so you should make an effort not to call Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()) so many times. If you use it more than once then it's a good idea to assigned the object to a variable and reuse it.